# Node-global-key-listener package Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-listener, keylistener, keylogger

I tried to implement `node-global-key-listener` package for my project and was successful in Windows build as well as in Mac.When I tried it in Ubuntu, for some reason the listener is not listening. I am currently in v20.04.

Upon tracing the code, this listener on the x11ServerKey does not seem to get called.

```js
this.proc.stdout.on("data", data => {
      const events = this._getEventData(data);
      for (let { event, eventId } of events) {
          const stopPropagation = !!this.listener(event);
          this.proc.stdin.write(`${stopPropagation ? "1" : "0"},${eventId}\n`);
      }
});
```

The process child does get initialized. Just listener not listening. The cpp part is a little outside of my expertise.

Any idea how to go about this? Let me know if you need more info.

Thank you so much.

I have traced the code up to the part where x11 server key is getting executed as a node child process. I think it is getting initialized but it is not emitting the `on 'data'` that handles the event.